# How can I create a shared volume with non-root access rights and docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Before I decided that it is probably a good idea to run the web service not as root in its Docker container, I simply had

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ...
    volumes:
     - .:/opt/app  # enables hot code reloading
     - uploads:/opt/app/uploads         
  ...
volumes:
    uploads:
        driver: local
```

in order to have the folder `/opt/app/uploads` within the client being identical to the `uploads` folder on the host.

Now, having added a new non-root user, I see the problem that the volume directory `/opt/app/uploads` gets assigned to the root, not to the user.

How can I fix that?

(I know that I can access the container and do it manually ... but I would like to know if there is a simpler solution; e.g. editing the `Dockerfile` or the `docker-compose.yml`)

Answer (score 0):

Was rather simple: Add the following line to the `Dockerfile`. Make sure the directory has the rights you want.

```
RUN mkdir -p /opt/app/uploads
```